# Understanding Arrays as part of the foreach in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Having:

```
$a as $key => $value;
```

is the same as having:

```
$a=array();
```

**?**

Comment: You made a typo, first statement should be: `$a as $key => $value;`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. $a = array() just initializes $a to an empty array, while foreach() loops over an existing array.

Comment: `$a as $key = $value;` isn't even a valid PHP statement.

Comment: @Fanis et all: Yes. I'm wondering if $a as $key=$value means, for each line, "put $a on a new array upon certain conditions".

Comment: $a as $key=$value will throw an error, as this syntax is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. It's more like

```
list($key, $value) = each($arr);
```

[See the manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

is identical to

```
$arr = array("one", "two", "three");
reset($arr);
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Also see

- [The `while` Control Structure](http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)
- [`list` — Assign variables as if they were an array](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)
- [`each` — Return the current key and value pair from an array and advance the array cursor](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php)
- [`reset` — Set the internal pointer of an array to its first element](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php)

Comment: It's the [`T_DOUBLE_ARROW` Parser Token](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php). You use it to denote a key belonging to a value in an [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax).

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. Kind a hard to find the meaning of => using it as a search string on google ;)

Comment: @MEM if you do not know basic things like this yet, I strongly encourage you to go through the [Language Reference of the PHP Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/langref.php). It's a lot to read, but it's well writenn and worth the read to get an idea of how the language works. The manual is actually one of the things where PHP really shines.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used => for some months already... and I understand enough (to solve some issues). But I really miss a solid (from the ground) formation, with a more expert developer. Normally however, I do found experienced developers, but only those that don't use filter_input, PDO, design patterns, subversion systems... and is the path I was looking for. I will take your like as a reference. :) (I do take php.net as one already and I tried to search for "=>" no luck however) :D Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it has to say

```
foreach($a as $key => $value)
```

Then, as far as I know,

```
foreach($a = array())
```

doesn't compile.

That said, if you foreach, you iterate through the elements of an array. With the 'as' keyword, you get pairs of key/value for each element, where $key would be the index by which you can get $value:

```
$value = $a[$key];
```

Did this answer your question? If not, please specify.

**edit:**
In other programming languages it would spell something like

```
foreach($key => $value in $a)
```

or (C#)

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<type1, type2> kv in a)
```

which I think is more intuitive, but basically the same.

Comment: That in makes so much difference on this comprehension. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the following:

```
$a = array('foo' => array('element1', 'element2'), 'bar' => array('sub1', 'sub2'));
```

if you use `$a as $key=> $value` in the foreach loop,

`$key` will be `'foo'`, and `$value` will be `array('element1', 'element2')` in the first iteration, in the second  `$key == 'bar'` and `$value == array('sub1', 'sub2')`.

Comment: Thanks. That help me see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop over an array using foreach, the array is the first expression inside the parenthesis.

It can be a variable, like $a, or an array literal like array(1, 2, 3). The following loops are identical:

With an array literal:

```
foreach(array(1, 2, 3) as $number)
    print($number);
```

With a variable:

```
$a = array(1, 2, 3);
foreach($a as $number)
    print($number);
```